# MySQL query is not working, for variable table name, column, row, and the value(which has to be insert in that specified location)?

Tags: mysql

Here is my php code. This update query is not working. I'm naïve in php, can anyone help??

```
    <?php
    include "connect.php";

    $table_name="CO208#";
    $date = "3-11-2017";
    $faculty = "15PEB203";
    $value = "0";

    $sql = "UPDATE $table_name SET $faculty = '$value' WHERE Date = '$date.'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    ?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: A lot of problems can be detected and resolved by [enabling exceptions in `mysqli`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578243/turning-query-errors-to-exceptions-in-mysqli) so mistakes aren't easily ignored.

Comment: You are not concatenating your string (building) correctly .. `"UPDATE " . $table_name . " SET " . $faculty . " = '" . $value . "' WHERE Date = '" . $date . "'"`

Comment: Like i have commented before.. Debug mysqli_error($con)  Side note: That's not how you prevent SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @zak PHP is perfectly capable of interpolating strings. Why do people insist that this is a problem?

Comment: The dot within `'$date.'` looks suspicious.

Comment: @Martin I removed dot in `$date.` but it still does not works.

Comment: @Zak Thanks it worked...

Comment: it works with this statement: $sql =    "UPDATE ``" .$table_name. "`` SET ``" .$faculty. "`` = '" .$value. "' WHERE Date = '" .$date. "' ";

Comment: Is it really updating? Because i'd believe that date should be in YYYY-mm-dd format...